# JS: Remove leading slashes, dots from relative path

Tags: javascript, relative-path, filepath

Using Javascript how would I remove any number of "../" from a relative path?

For instance:

```
Before - '../../../folder1/folder2/my-file.php'
After  - 'folder1/folder2/my-file.php'

Before - '../folder1/my-file.php'
After  - 'folder1/my-file.php'
```

I've searched multiple keywords both here and at Google and can't seem to find a Javascript based solution, most are PHP which is not what I'm needing.  Also, I'd like to avoid a regex solution if possible.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Also, I'd like to avoid a regex solution if possible.

In JavaScript, a regular expression is probably the best way to do this; but you *could* do it with a loop instead:

```
var str = "../../../folder1/folder2/my-file.php";
var result = str;
while (result.substring(0, 3) === "../") {
    result = result.substring(3);
}
```

---

Using a regular expression and `String#replace`:

```
var str = "../../../folder1/folder2/my-file.php";
var result = str.replace(/^(?:\.\.\/)+/, "");
```

That regular expression says: Match the start of the string (`^`) and then one or more `../` substrings, and replace them with `""` (e.g., nothing). You need the backslashes in there because both `.` and `/` are special characters in regular expression literals, but we want them to actually be `.` and `/` in your string. The `(?:___)` construct groups those three characters together without forming a capture group.

More on regular expressions on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) or (much, much less clearly) in the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.5).

Comment: T.J. thank you for both solutions, the regex is a lot cleaner so I'll use that one. Thanks again! Here's a fiddle for any visual learners following this question: http://jsfiddle.net/X69Fd/

Comment: @BD_Design: Good deal, glad that helped. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
var source = '../../../folder1/folder2/my-file.php';
    after = source.replace(/\.\.\//g, '');

console.log(after);
```

Comment: Thanks jAndy, this solution works but I think I'm going to go back on what I said and use T.J.'s regex solution below. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @BD_Design: jAndy's solution uses regex as well. The reason it looks a bit different is that it removes `../` *anywhere* in the string rather than only at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not wedded to regular expressions you can use the string lastIndexOf method:

```
function pathStrip(url){
    ax= url.lastIndexOf('./')+1;
    return ax? url.substring(ax+1):url;
}
```

pathStrip('../../../folder1/folder2/my-file.php');

If there are no './' or '../' the string is returned unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about your folder name to be constant you can use substring

```
var str = "../../../folder1/folder2/my-file.php";
var result = str.substring(str.indexOf('folder1'));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the folder paths will be changing so this solution doesn't fit the bill. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

If someone would like also to remove a single leading dot with multiple leading dot

use this regex

```
str.replace(/^(?:\.\.\/|\.\/)+/, '')
```

I just updated the regex that @.J. Crowder mentioned above by adding `|\.\/` so it also match any "dots" followed by single "slash"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-regex approach:

```
var chunks = str.split('/');
var result = '';
var alternative = [];
for(var i=0;i<chunks.length;i++)
{
    if(chunks[i] !== '.' && chunks[i]!=='..')
    {
        result += chunks[i]+(i <(chunks.length -1) ? '/' : '');
        alternative.push(chunks[i]);
    }
}
alternative = alternative.join('/');
```

Result and alternative will be `folder1/folder2/my-file.php`
This is much like T.J. Crowders answer, except paths like `./somescript.php` will be stripped from their initial `./` aswell... which somewhat improves safety...

Comment: Thanks Elias, this is also a good solution - I ended up going back on my word and using the regex solution T.J. provided .  Thanks again!